# Viber Bot does not start

Tags: python, flask, viber, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

I run my Viber bot through `gunicorn` and `flask` on server. But when I do `curl` request I get error

```
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host chatapi.viber.com left intact
{"status":1,"status_message":"Result[HttpRequest[POST / HTTP/1.1]@3f742f36 > HttpResponse[HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR]@16f0ed02] null","chat_hostname":"SN-CHAT-01_"}
```

when I open url my site I have

```
Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

from viberbot import Api
from viberbot.api.bot_configuration import BotConfiguration
from viberbot.api.messages import KeyboardMessage
from viberbot.api.messages.text_message import TextMessage
import logging

from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberFailedRequest
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberMessageRequest
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberSubscribedRequest

from keyboard import keyboard_menu

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

app = Flask(__name__)
viber = Api(BotConfiguration(
    name='name',
    avatar='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg',
    auth_token='token'
))

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    logger.debug("received request. post data: {0}".format(request.get_data()))
    # every viber message is signed, you can verify the signature using this method
    if not viber.verify_signature(request.get_data(), request.headers.get('X-Viber-Content-Signature')):
        return Response(status=403)

    # this library supplies a simple way to receive a request object
    viber_request = viber.parse_request(request.get_data())

    if isinstance(viber_request, ViberMessageRequest):
        message = TextMessage(text="test", keyboard=keyboard_menu)
        # lets echo back
        viber.send_messages(viber_request.sender.id, [
            message
        ])

    elif isinstance(viber_request, ViberSubscribedRequest):
        viber.send_messages(viber_request.get_user.id, [
            TextMessage(text="thanks for subscribing!")
        ])
    elif isinstance(viber_request, ViberFailedRequest):
        logger.warn("client failed receiving message. failure: {0}".format(viber_request))

    return Response(status=200)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**curl**

```
curl -# -i -g -H "X-Viber-Auth-Token:token" -d @viber.json -X POST https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook -v
```

**viber.json**

```
{
  "url": "https://my.site.com"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending a post request when testing your url?

Comment: @nickvokey I'm just doing curl request "... POST https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook -v"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send POST request to that endpoint, like Viber server would do that, but using `cURL`. So you'll be able to see the error.

Or update root logger to see a reason of 500 error. Propose to configure it like in [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/#basic-configuration) (see [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/#basic-configuration) for more details):

```py
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})

app = Flask(__name__)
```

And the last think:

> when I open url my site I have
>
> ```
> Method Not Allowed
>
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
> ```

That's because when you are opening that url in browser it sends GET request, but endpoints accepts only `POST` http method.